# Make image with wrapping content responsive

Tags: css, responsive-design

I need to create an image with some info next to it, the info is like a name, university and a follow button, just exactly like this demo

[image]

How to create this structure without getting a problem while resizing the browser, assuming it takes up 20% of a section width?

html:

```
<section id="some-section">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div id="img-container">
                    <img src="avatar.png" alt="herp_image">
                </div>
                <div id="hero_details">
                    <h2>John Doe</h2>
                    <span>Professor</span>
                    <span>Neuroscience</span>
                    <span>University of Oxford</span>
                    <div id="Contact">
                        <a href="#">Follow</a>
                        <a href="#">Message</a>
                    </div>

                </div>     
            </div>
        </section>
```

CSS:

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

#some-section {
    background: #eee;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 20%;
    padding: 10px;
    background: lightgreen;
    line-height: 1.5;
    font-size: 0.9em;
}

#img-container {
    width: 100px;
    height: 200px;
    max-width: 60%;
    max-height: 80%;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

#hero_details {
    max-width: 50%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin-bottom: auto;
}

#hero_details span {
    font-size: 0.85em; 
}


#hero_details h2 {
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}
```

This code aligns items correctly just before resizing the browser to lower width
but seems very verbose and not efficient in the term of responsiveness as I see.

Comment: Sorry. I cannot add a comment. So I answer you by an answer without your situation detail. I will not give you the specified source code.
You can do this with some simple CSS unit like vm, vh. It is called responsive (for a keyword). For detail, please visit this site: [W3C CSS Unit](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp)

Comment: i know about vm, vh, and all responsive units, the problem is that  images always have a special case when comes to responsiveness, and alone can be managed but now it is bound to some info that makes it harder to make it responsive, and this what causes the trouble for me

Comment: can you add your code

Comment: @Sharvan Thanks  i added it, it works fine with the full browser width but not after resizing, if i need it to work for smaller widths i need to add too many breakpoints till the font become unreadable!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try this. The image and content section will be equal column height as per your reference image. I hope this solution will be helpful.

```css
img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
 box-sizing:border-box;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.wrapper {
    display: flex;
}
.hero_details {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    padding: 0 0 0 10px;
}
.hero_details_inner {
    width: 100%;
    align-items: flex-start;
}
.hero_details .contact {
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
}
.wrapper .contact .btn-flow {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #000;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    padding: 3px 4px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
.wrapper .contact a {
    margin: 0 6px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<section id="some-section">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="img-container">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x300" alt="herp_image">
        </div>
        <div class="hero_details">
            <div class="hero_details_inner">
                <h2>John Doe</h2>
                <p>Professor</p>
                <p>Senior Group Leader and professor of surgical Oncology</p>
                <p>University of Oxford</p>
            </div>
            <div class="contact">
                <a class="btn-flow" href="#">Follow</a>
                <a href="#">Message</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you, this doesn't help much as i need to maintain the same structure whenever browser get resized, the h2 is aligned to the top of the image, the buttons aligned to the bottom and the main info are in the middle, your markup seems weird to me, you used ul and i think it is not suitable here, Thanks for your trying to help!

Comment: In my browser working good. I don't know what you exactly trying to do. I follow your reference image.

Comment: sorry my friend if my question is not clear enough for you, but it should be.. i want to maintain the side of info with the side of the image be resized with each other so always the name be aligned with the top line of the image , and the buttons be aligned to the bottom line of the image, and this should be maintained in all screen sizes, your soln makes it in small screens , but in my laptop full screen width, the buttons are aligned to middle line of the image, thanks for your patience!

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution:

```css
.container .img {
  text-align: center;
}

.container .details {
  border-left: 3px solid #ded4da;
}

.container .details p {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: left;
  word-break: keep-all;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 img">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/150x200/CCCCCC&text=Image" alt="" class="img-rounded"> </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 details">
      <blockquote>
        <h5>John Doe</h5>
        <small>professor</small>
      </blockquote>
      <p>Senior Group Leader and professor of surgical Oncology University Of Oxford</p>
      <div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">Follow</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn">Message</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

After i Checked the Solution of @Shavran, I have modified it a little to achieve the maximum benefit of it and this is the final code:

html:

```
  <section id="some-section">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="img-container">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x300" alt="herp_image">
      </div>
      <div class="hero_details">  
        <h2>John Doe</h2>
        <div class="hero_details_inner">       
          <p>Professor</p>
          <p>Senior Group Leader and professor of surgical Oncology</p>
          <p>University of Oxford</p>
       </div>
       <div class="contact">
         <a class="btn-flow" href="#">Follow</a>
         <a href="#">Message</a>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
  </section>
```

CSS:

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    font-size: calc(11px + 0.4vw);
}
.hero_details {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    padding: 0 0 0 10px;
}
.hero_details_inner {
    width: 100%;
    align-items: flex-start;
}

.hero_details_inner p{
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
    line-height: 2;
}
.hero_details .contact {
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
}
.wrapper .contact .btn-flow {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #000;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    padding: 3px 4px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
.wrapper .contact a {
    margin: 0 6px 0 0;
}
```